# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities error when publishing App & App Clip to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, info.plist, apple-appclips

When I try to upload my augmented reality App and App Clip to App Store Connect from my XCode project (XCode 13.3), I get the following error message :

*App Store Connect Operation Error
Invalid required device capabilities. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities values [arkit] in the Info.plist of app clip 'MyApp.app/AppClips/MyAppClip.app' must match the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities values [arkit] in the Info.plist of the app. Match the device capabilities between your app and app clip. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90845 for id cd915e8a-4777-4c9a-9dee-af3a92b0175b*

It is worth noting that both the App and AppClip work fine when I build & run them on my iPhone.

However, I have double checked my info.plist files in both my App and App Clip and they both specify the ARKit capability in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities field, as you can see in these screenshots :

[image: App Info.plist file]

[image: App Clip Info.plist file]

[image: Error Message]